# 403 Forbidden / authentification blocked by token sequelize

Tags: node.js, validation, authentication

So I create my route user and I use this tutorial https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-jwt-authentication-mysql/ to add the token and Authentication Token + validation name. Everything work great. But then when I beginning to create my route Comment (acces for every user), I had normaly the auth but even with the token Postman send me an "No token provided!". I have to add this token and autorize the acces but I don't know how. If somebody know how to do it, it would be great :D thx ! This is how I add my token on Postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPmrq.png)

Here is my code:

My route comment:

```html
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const commentCtrl = require("../controllers/comment");
const { authJwt } = require("../middleware");

router.post("/upload", [authJwt.verifyToken], commentCtrl.createComment);

module.exports = router;
```

The middleware token :

```html
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/auth.config.js");

verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({
      message: "No token provided!"
    });
  }
  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Unauthorized!"
      });
    }
    req.id = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};

const authJwt = {
  verifyToken: verifyToken,
};

module.exports = authJwt;
```

```html
const authJwt = require("./authJwt");
const verifySignUp = require("./verifySignUp");

module.exports = {
  authJwt,
  verifySignUp
};
```

My verification SignUp:

```html
const { User } = require("../models");

checkDuplicateEmail = async (req, res, next) => { 
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: req.body.email
      }
    }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.status(400).send({
          message: "Failed! Email is already in use!"
        });
        return;
      }
      next();
    });
};

const verifySignUp = {
  checkDuplicateEmail: checkDuplicateEmail
};
module.exports = verifySignUp;
```

And here is my user.controllers when is send the token:

```html
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/auth.config");
const { User } = require("../models");


module.exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
    res.status(400).send({
        status: false,
        message: 'une erreur dans create est survenu'
    });
} else {
  let { nom, prenom, email, password, status} = req.body;
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
    const user = await User.create({
      nom, prenom, email,  password, status
    })
    .then((user) => res.status(201).send(user)).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).send(error);
  });
  }
};


module.exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not found." });
      }
   
      const passwordIsValid =   bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(401).send({
          accessToken: null,
          message: "Invalid Password!"
        });
      }
      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // 24 hours
      });
      res.status(200).send({
        id: user.id,
        nom: user.nom,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        accessToken: token
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would have helped if you had provided a screenshot of where you are putting your token on postman, make sure you are using the appropriate header. According to your code, you are searching the 'x-access-token' header, so in postman, you should attach your jwt token to the same header property. It should be something like this:

[postman x-access-token demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FezhQ.png)

Comment: You suggestion work, thank you  ! Just in case for other I add the screenshot that you asked me on my issue.